Possible to move a Windows365 CloudPC out of its In-Grace Period back to deployed
We have a number of Windows365 CloudPCs provisioned in MS365.
One of these (through an oversight!) has moved into the "in-grace period" of 7 days before it is deprovisioned and deleted.
We have corrected the reason that it was (automatically) moved to the Grace Period, but cannot work out how to get it back to "Provisioned" status?

Does this happen automatically at some point (hopefully "soon")?
Do we have to take some other action?
Are we screwed?

Many thanks
